# Would compiling a regex into native assembly be faster than PCRE or other Regex engines?

Tags: c++, regex, perl, assembly, pcre

I was thinking about an improvement. I'm currently doing lots of text processing of log files.

I don't mean to say PCRE is slow/fast or any other implementation for that matter.

The language I'm writing in is primarily Perl. I know it has a powerful regex engine and I know it's more expressive than PCRE.

I have this idea about making a small regex engine in C++ that would compile a regex to raw nasm.

I'm aware PCRE is quite complex and my assumption is that I could skip a lot of things done by PCRE in terms of non-necessary processing. And I could certainly make this faster than Perl since it operates with vm-like opcodes and all sorts of things that could be considered as being overhead.

I already started an implementation some time ago. I'm not going to post it here since I don't have any problems with it, I could carry it out to the end and obtain a regex engine capable of doing captures, capable of interpreting `+` `*` `^` `$` , character classes (although I haven't done the part where I'll convert the regex to assembly language)

Would this be a good idea or a bad idea? What could go wrong in terms of reaching a good performance with this?

tl;dr => could a C++ mini-regex engine that would produce native assembly be faster than established regex implementations?

Comment: What makes you think your engine will be faster?

Comment: As long as it handles all of the cases you need it to handle, and you do some rudimentary benchmarks, I say go for it. It's more work than most people are willing to attempt, so more power to you!

Comment: @PSIAlt that's exactly my question. would it be faster?

Comment: @joeframbach I'm willing to go the distance if it brings benefits in terms of speed. I am surely going to do some benchmarks, but before I go any further I want to ask for oppinions if it would be a good/bad idea. Thank you

Comment: What language is the Perl RE engine written in? Also C++ has a RE template library that may help. or see boost for pre C++11 version.

Comment: @LokiAstari  [The Perl RE engine is written in C](http://perl5.git.perl.org/perl.git/blob/HEAD:/regexec.c)

Comment: Perl, including its RE engine, is written in C

Comment: Are you sure the processing is the bottleneck, and not the file I/O? Often file processing is limited by the speed of the hard disks.

Comment: The question by OP wan't about Perl being written in C; it was about the regex engine executing the query in machine code, which would require the Perl engine to generate machine code for each regex.  I'm guessing it doesn't do that.

Comment: @average: What's this bit about about Perl being "more expressive than PCRE"?  PCRE *is defined* as "Perl-compatible regular expression".

Comment: @average: I'm sure you are pleased your question got closed.  The SO powers that be seem to dislike lots of very interesting questions.  This one fits in the "how can I program X" category that SO is supposed to handle pretty well IMHO, but what you discover is that in any large crowd, there's a group of people that don't like something, e.g., your question.  If you think your question is unreasonably closed, I suggest you make your voice heard in Meta.  There are far too many closures of questions like this happening.

Comment: My question wasn't anywhere near "how do I program X". I know how to program it. My question was whether it's worth doing considering the existing implementations. Thanks for suggesting containg Meta but that's too much overhead.

Comment: But thank you to everyone who answered. It was nice to get oppinions.. as long as it lasted..

Answer (score 6):

I think the answer to this one is pretty obvious. Ideally, yes, it could be. But even if you're *very* clever at this kind of thing it would take a very large development effort to get to a point where, for the most part, you're only slightly better than available libraries — and even longer to work all of the bugs out. So there's not much point in it.

Comment: but what if I just need `|` `*` `+` `^` `$` and character classes and captures ? does restricting the domain to just these make the volume of work required closer to a realistic thing ?

Comment: I would generally agree with this.  Especially if your intent is to use this to process logs.  I would think thatif you are getting to the point where you need to do a bunch of manipulation on log data to get information about how your application is running, that you might better spend that time adding instrumentation to the application to better store the data you are trying to get at.

Comment: @MikeBrant so you're hinting at storing the data in a form that is easier to process. perhaps you're suggesting indexing it in some way or storing it in something where queries can be made on it ?

Comment: @average incidentally, the overhead of Perl for a task like this is much less than you probably think. The regex engine, in particular, is very well optimized, and since Perl's operations skew towards text processing, well-written code will already spend most of its time doing useful work, and waste very little in the runloop. It's *math* that makes Perl look slow :)

Comment: @average Yes exactly.  There are a number of really good solutions out there for this sort of thing as well (Graylog for instance)

Comment: If you need `|` and want to outperform existing solutions, you'll need to also implement trie optimizations as is done with Perl.

Answer (score 6):

Perl's regexp is fast but not blazingly fast.  See [Russ Cox's analysis of Perl vs. Thompson-style regexp engines](http://swtch.com/~rsc/regexp/regexp1.html) for an eye popping demonstration on the difference in performance, and theory on how to do it right.

If you don't want to implement Thompson/Cox's scheme, you should consider [Ragel](http://www.complang.org/ragel/), a very fast regular expression processor.  Ragel does the hard work of building efficient automatons, and then generates code for target compiler languages.  It lets the compiler do the hard work of converting "to machine code".

It is likely to be the engine you are contemplating building.

If these aren't good enough, you should track down recent work by IBM in extremely fast stream matchers.  I think papers by [Davide Pasetto](http://www.linkedin.com/pub/davide-pasetto/5/713/2b9) are probably relevant.

Comment: thanks for the suggestion. I want to ask about this Ragel, I want to generate raw assembly with it, so outside the realm of typical C or C++ or Java. I want to squeeze the last drop of performance I can out of it so that's why I'd need assembly to be generated. I'm also have an internal conflict of whether this is a good/bad idea given that gcc/g++ these days generates smarter assembly code than a person could write manually..

Comment: I know the Russ Cox link, thanks for mentioning it. That's exactly what I wanted to follow for the implementation

Comment: Unless you want to out-optimize most compilers, you're pretty much better off letting a good compiler generate the code.

Comment: @average, if you're wondering if it's a good idea, then my guess is that it wouldn't be a good idea for you. +1 on Ragel. I don't think there can be much/any noticeable improvement over it in this case.

Comment: @average: FWIW, Cox offers his source code; you can use that instead of Ragel.

Comment: That article (effectively) shows that `perl -e'$n=20;$_="a"x$n;eval "/".("a?"x$n).("a"x$n)."/"'` is slow. If you swap `"a?"` for `"a??"` it becomes fast. I tested the `"a??"` variant on a string of one million `a`'s and it managed it in less than half a second. `perl -e'$n=1_000_000;$_="a"x$n;eval "/".("a??"x$n).("a"x$n)."/"'`. You could have also just put a `$` at the end of the regex, and it would have much better performance. `perl -e'$n=1_000_000;$_="a"x$n;eval "/^".("a?"x$n).("a"x$n)."$/";'` takes about 20 milliseconds. If your regex is slow in Perl, you probably wrote it poorly.

Answer (score 3):

Just do a benchmark. Take a regexp which is quite simple, yet something you would commonly use. Then make a hard-coded version of that regexp. Compare using realistic amount of data, where operation takes a long enough for speedup to matter.

I think any good regexp engine's inner loop is already pretty optimized, using both state-of-the-art text matching algorithms, and are optimized to do them fast. So good luck getting faster with your own code, when expression is not something trivial (char classes for example).

Obviously there is overhead, you could hard-code stuff doing it your way and achieve a nice linear speedup, *all else being equal*. But that is secondary to having good algorithms, and if you are not familiar with concept of algorithmic complexity, [read up on that](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Computational_complexity_theory) first.

---

But there is one critical thing, which is almost a showstopper for real use. Regexp engine must be correct. It must find what it is supposed,, with zero false positives. Bad things can happen if you get false match or miss a match, such as data corruption. How do you achieve high enough confidence on your engine to dare to use it?

Create one for fun, sure. For real production use... ummm...

---

If you are potentially serious, you need automated test from the start. For something like regexp, you also want code coverage analysis for your tests. As you will have deterministic input and output, no user input or anything, ultimately you should aim for 100% coverage of relevant parts of the code, both for engine and for generated code of your test regexps. Oh, and don't forget automatic benchmarks either, when goal is speed! Of course you want to get coding and not care about this stuff at first, and that's fine, but set up the infrastructure from start, and when you test your code, write it as automated test, resist urge to do ad-hoc testing manually (except as a step of writing an automated test case). Your project has much higher chance of succeeding, if you do things right.

For generated code, [LLVM](http://llvm.org/) is probably what you want to use, instead of assembler of some particular CPU.

Comment: Yes sure. I am going to develop it in my free time, as a hobby. If I'm able to weed out the bugs, I will do some benchmarks, and if all goes well, it'll be on github at some point. But right now, I'm just trying to find out if it would make any sense to work on it in the first place. Like for example, if there was some secret magic sauce that regex implementations have and is hard to implement, then I'd probably abandon the idea altogether

Comment: Added a suggestion for ultimately achieving production quality reliability, and suggestion to look at LLVM (also used by *clang*, for example).

Answer (score 2):

You could probably squeeze out significantly more performance from a regex compiled to machine instructions.  Whether it makes sense to do so depends completely on how you amortize the cost.

If you are trying to reach the specific goal of parsing log files and have a deadline, then it might not make sense to even consider this until you've *proven* that existing libraries (including [Google's RE2](http://code.google.com/p/re2/)) are too slow for you.  Worrying about your RE performance before you've determined it's a bottleneck is a classic case of premature optimization.

If, however, you want to do this as a challenge and learning exercise, and there's no deadline looming, then by all means give it a shot.  Be prepared for a lot of work, and don't forget to write a lot of test cases because there will be bugs.  Your regex engine will be the critical foundation of the overall work product, and you cannot afford for it to misbehave in production.

Good luck!